# How can I stop Outlook from automatically signing me out?

Tags: security, outlook-365

Every day or two, I have to log back into my Outlook 365 account online. How can I stop Outlook logging out?

Comment: I believe I gave an answer here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115170/how-to-avoid-constant-logging-out-from-outlook-web-app/115435#115435